# jquery - How to place a waiting / loading gif image on top of a div?

Tags: jquery, css, overlay

I need to put the `wait.gif` wrapped in a `div` on top of another `div` for period of time.

I got 2 problems:

1. How am I gonna position the waiting image on top of the div.
2. My setTimeout is not working.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#div1 {
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 background-color: #F0F0F0;
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
}

#btnLoad {
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1.6.4min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#waiting").hide();
});

$(function() {
 function goFoo() {
  var width = $("#div1").outerWidth();
  var height = $("#div1").outerHeight();

  $("#waiting").css({
   postion: "absolute",
   top: height + 10 + "px",
   left: width + 10 + "px"
  }).show();
  $("#div1").html($("#waiting"));
  setTimeout(goFoo, 5000);
 }

 $("#btnLoad").click(function() {
  goFoo();
  $("#div1").css('background-color', '#FDF5E6');
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1"> </div>
<div id="waiting" ><img src="wait.gif" /> </div>
<input type="button" id="btnLoad" value="Click" />
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE: www.jsfiddle.net is under maintenance thats why I pasted all my codes.

Comment: What do you mean by on top? Do you want to align the image?

Comment: I want the image to be in the center of the div. I want to make it work like when you're waiting for the table to reload.

Answer (score 1):

The timeout should have a function inside, otherwise it gets executed straight away.
setTimeout(function(){xxxx},5000);

If you want to position over div1, use z-index css property.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following setTimeout

```
setTimeout(function() {$("#div1").css('background-color', '#FDF5E6')}, 5000);
```

setTimeout expects a function, not an *executed* function. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout for more info.

Comment: In the current example, goFoo is never run... Anyways, give people a +1 if they help you, and don't change your question, that is just frustrating for the effort everyone has put in :-)

Answer (score 1):

To position the image above the other element you can use `position:absolute;` and `z-index`. See: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp for some info.

Your `setTimeout` does not work as it expects a function like:

```
setTimeout(function(){$("#div1").css('background-color', '#FDF5E6');}, 5000);
```

Comment: The parent element of the `position:absolute;` element still needs `position:relative;`

Answer (score 1):

- Give div1 a `position:relative` property
- Give waiting a `display:none` property instead of hiding it with
  jQuery
- Give waiting a `position:absolute` property

Then the button load event:

```
$('#btnLoad').click(function() {
   $(this).append($('#waiting').css({top:10, left:10});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just added my jQuery plugin elementOverlay  to github. It's not documented and 100% tested yet, but should work.

Following code will put an overlay over a form until the ajax post has finished:

```
var overlay = $('#yourForm').elementOverlay({title: '<img src="wait.gif" />'});
$.post('/some/action', $('#yourForm').serialize(), function(data) {
    overlay.elementOverlay('hide');

    // handle response
});
```

It uses jQueryUI to style the overlay.

https://github.com/jgauffin/griffin.jquery.tools/blob/master/Source/Plugins/jquery.griffin.elementoverlay.js